# deploying magento on google cloud computing

Tags: magento, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want to move my magento site from AWS to Google and I want to make sure I'm doing it the right way as I am new with google cloud computing.
These are the steps I'm planning on doing:

1. create an instance and install redis and my magento store on it.
2. create sql for my DB
3. create a snapshop of this instance
4. create a template from this instance
5. create a group of instances with the template
6. create a load balancer and connect it with the instances group

is that the correct way to build a solid and fairly scalable magento site on GCC?

are there any services on google cloud I can use to make my store even more fast and scalable?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 3):

That's a fairly good way to deploy, but you can offload a few of those to managed services by GCP.

- Use Click-To-Deploy solution for Magento (https://cloud.google.com/launcher/solution/bitnami-launchpad/magento?q=magento)
- Launch another Click-To-Deploy solution for Redis (https://cloud.google.com/launcher/solution/bitnami-launchpad/redis?q=redis)
- Launch a Cloud SQL instance (https://cloud.google.com/sql/)
- Update your Magento instance with the configuration for these servers
- Use this as a template to launch instances-group
- Put this groups behind a load balancer

Why is this better?

- You don't have to manage your SQL DB security and scaling
- You get redis and magento using simple clicks, saves a lot of time
- All you need to manage are your settings. Even if you wanted to update your magento to newer upgrades on better servers

Bonus: You should also make use of a CDN for your static resources and Cloud CDN (https://cloud.google.com/cdn/) will be helpful there.

Further Read: Go through this to get a sense of what else can you do with GCP (https://cloud.google.com/solutions/commerce/)